# Does reviewing queues have any gains for me as a Stack Overflow user?

Tags: discussion, reputation, review, moderation

Due to my reputation on Stack Overflow, I have access to different review queues. I want to know if it will change my score/reputation or if it will only provide me some badges?

Maybe this part seems a bit odd, but why do some users spend so much time in the review queues? Is it something about their passion about Stack Overflow or their passion to help others inside the community or does it have some other reasons which I've missed?

P.S. I have read some information like *[Why can people edit my posts? How does editing work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/editing)* and *[Who are the site moderators, and what is their role here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/site-moderators)*, but I will be grateful to have your answer about this.

---

After seeing the answers from users below this questions, I understood that this question is a bit far from the soul of Stack Overflow. The whole idea in this community is to help each other and keep the programmers' atmosphere live and ongoing. So please accept my apologies for asking such a question, but the answers to this question might help others to understand this fact much better. :)

Comment: The site doesn't become useful by itself. That needs strict moderation and due to the size of SO, it needs lots of hands to help out. You'll not earn rep, you earn a few badges but most importantly: you help future visitors to find what they are looking for more quickly because the reviewers removed all the chaff

Comment: @Rene so there is not direct rewarding system for moderators? Their gain will be to be a part of community which is clean and useful for them and others. Am I right?

Comment: There is no reward system for mods, no. Some days the opposite...

Comment: SO has an existing reputation system. It's preposterous not to reward mod effort by using it.

Comment: Yeah, seems very weird. Its like, reputation is important until you get enough to be useful, and then we'll stop bothering with it.

Comment: I had the exact same qn, so thanks @VSB for asking it and keeping it up!  Knowing what you get (or don't get) for your efforts is nice. No need to apologize.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

- If you find the community reviewing mechanisms and customs sub-optimal, now you have some saying to move the system into a better direction.
- After every 1000 reviews, you get a golden badge. Having many golden badges doesn't grant you any privileges(*), but they have a similar secondary effect if you deal with others, like if you had a high reputation.
- You can cast close/reopen votes, so you can initiate the closure or reopening of questions where you feel you need to.
- On SO, the Close Votes review queue is in a catastrophal state, it has been around 9000 questions since years. A good-working moderation mechanism would require a quick, clear and deterministic Close/Leave Open decision in all the dubious cases. We simply don't have enough reviewers, and no work-around for this problem was found until now. Your daily 40 reviews would help more than it seems!

<sub>(*) Actually, the nomination on a moderator election requires to have some moderation badges, but these are easy to get, and the chance that you will become a mod ever, is practically negligible.</sub>

Comment: In fact, the Close votes queue in SO reached 100K several times, only that some changes were implemented and it went down to ~10K.

Comment: @fedorqui It happened 3 or 4 years ago. Now it seems to be stabilized around 9000, and a large part of the reviews ends with timeout.

Comment: Every 1,000!!....  (I'm on 26.........)

Answer (score 11):

You earn nothing except, like for me, some satisfaction that you have helped the community. Others might have other reasons.

I am a mod on another platform and yes, like there, it's time given away.

A side note, SO's idea of moderation is more open than some other platforms, as thus any users with the minimum score can moderate. Don’t see that as a useless thing as you can’t earn rep that way, but see it as, unlike a lot of Q/A sites, SO trusts their user base with the minimum rep to do moderation tasks (and they trust the tasks they do, as a true moderator rarely reverts community moderation results, like closing).

Answer (score 6):

Reputation points are artificial and easily gamed. They're not a reflection of a person's actual reputation in a site's community. Being a participant in community moderation, including using the review queues, is how you actually get a good reputation in a site's community.

But the queues also show you a different subset of the site's questions that you see from the front page. They may alert you to other questions you could answer and then also get your points from.

Comment: perhaps this issue could be alleviated if reputation points correlated more closely with actual work provided. your tone in the last sentence is unnecessarily condescending.

Comment: Good edit to this answer... 